# Model training hangs forever when using a Tensorboard callback with an LSTM layer (cuDNN implementation) - Tensorflow 2.3

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

We decided to migrate our codebase from Tensorflow 1.13.1 to Tensorflow 2.3.

Everything seems to work properly, except when training a LSTM model with a Tensorboard callback. The training process hangs forever after the first batch (maybe Tensorboard waits for never coming summary ops ?).

After some investigations, it seems that the issue comes from the LSTM layer relying on the cuDNN implementation. Indeed, everything works as intended when forcing Tensorflow to fall back on the vanilla LSTM layer implementation (giving it incompatible arguments with the cuDNN implementation, c.f. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM).

Any suggestions to fix this ? Does anyone has any idea on why Tensorboard does not work with cuDNN implementation of the LSTM layer ?

```py
# Callbacks
log_dir = './logs'
callbacks = [TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)] # Training works without this callback

# Model
words = Input(shape=(max_sequence_length,))
x = Embedding(input_dim, embedding_size, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(words)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(40, return_sequences=True))(x)  # Setting recurrent_dropout = 0.1 makes the training work (using the vanilla LSTM implementation)
hidden = concatenate([
    GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x),
    GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x),
])
hidden = add([hidden, Dense(40, activation='relu')(hidden)])
out = Dense(3, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(hidden)
model = Model(inputs=words, outputs=[out])
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# Fit
fit_history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_data,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

UPDATE :
Tried it on another computer (Windows 10) and everything seems to work correctly...
However, computers at work are mostly on Windows 7 (issue happened on 2 separate PC), and we are using virtual envs.
Another hint : can the fact that python and our library are installed on different hard drives may cause the issue? (that's one of the similarities of the setups where the issue arises)

Comment: Use tensorflow 1.4.0 and python 3.6x....a lot of features such as the tensorflow.contrib, has been removed from tensorflow versions greater than 1.4.0, so try using 1.4.0 and 3.6x python, this should probably work, if your code is too slow, go to google Colaboratoty, it's totally free,  you can run your high end code using Google's hardware.

Comment: Hello @ROG_SHAKHYAR and thank you for your reply. However, we really want to upgrade our tensorflow version to a recent one (at least 2.X). We are working on a codebase that will be reused by many people at work, and that needs to be as updated as possible. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: Probably try reinstalling cudnn with everything enabled if you are using installer, and always store python and other stuff related to python in the same disk as changing directory can be messy specially to different drives, anyways if nothing works, then use binary installation of tensorflow and follow the tensorflow website to install other dependencies

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. That excatly the same conda env on windows 10, code runs fine. But when it runs on windows 7, added tensorboard callback, it hangs forever. Do you have any clue / have fixed this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately we didn't find a way to fix this .... 
So we gave up using Tensorboard on windows 7 computers (we just added a check when adding the callback). It seems like this is a very specific error (windows 7 / Tensorflow 2.x / LSTM / cudNN), and it seems very unlikely to find an easy fix to this ...

Comment: As you have mentioned in the post and comment section the issue will be usually with the OS and the dependent packages compatibility. Anyhow you have upgraded the OS and fixed the issue. But still if you want to use it on windows 7 then you can raise a bug on GitHub.